# problems with \widthof after updating to TL 2017

Tags: tikz-pgf

I could swear that the following example worked prior to 2017 w/o problems. After updating to TL2017 this error message is the result:

```
!Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@
```

Any hints what's going wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[text width=\widthof{ABC}] at (0,0) {bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There is another question: How to do with math expressions?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[text width=width("n=10"))] at (0,0) {bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This does not work, but this variant does:

```
\node[text width=width("{$n=10$}")] at (0,0) {bla};
```

Comment: It works for me with TL2014, from there on (TL15, TL16, TL17) it give your error (which I don't find surprising).

Comment: Thanks for your Investigation. But what do I have to change?

Comment: Try `text width=width("ABC")` instead

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that does not change anything.

Comment: `\node[text width=width("ABC")] at (0,0) {bla};` works fine for me.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Of course it works for me, too. I first overlooked the missing \ after the =-sign. Many thanks to you both!

Comment: @Jürgen You can also remove the `calc` package...

Comment: Ok, eventually I found the answer (see above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier versions of TikZ defined a `\widthof` macro that could be used the way you have done, and you'll probably still find examples of that around. In version 3 of TikZ however, you can use the `width` function of the math engine instead, and say

```
\node[text width=width("ABC")] at (0,0) {bla};
```

Regarding your last question, the key difference between your working and non-working code is the presence of the braces. I don't know exactly what happens, but the `=` somehow trips the parser I think. Hence, this works as well:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[text width=width("{n=10}")] at (0,0) {bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```